# Laravel Tailwind authentication scaffolding issue

Tags: laravel, authentication, npm, webpack, tailwind-css

So I am currently playing around with Laravel and Tailwind. I have created a project and working through some initial views. The next to do was to add auth scaffolding to the project.

I tried Googling around, found https://aregsar.com/blog/2020/create-laravel-project-with-tailwind-ui-and-auth/. I also checked a couple of other results which had the same pointers.

So when I run `composer require laravel-frontend-presets/tailwindcss --dev`, no problems. Next up I run the following.

```
php artisan ui tailwindcss --auth
Tailwind CSS scaffolding installed successfully.
Tailwind CSS auth scaffolding installed successfully.
Please run "npm install && npm run dev" to compile your fresh scaffolding.
```

No issues...however, when I try and run npm install, I get the following...

```
npm install && npm run dev
```

> npm ERR! code ERESOLVE npm ERR! ERESOLVE unable to resolve dependency
> tree npm ERR! npm ERR! While resolving: undefined@undefined npm ERR!
> Found: tailwindcss@2.2.7 npm ERR! node_modules/tailwindcss npm ERR!
> dev tailwindcss@"^2.2.6" from the root project npm ERR! npm ERR! Could
> not resolve dependency: npm ERR! peer tailwindcss@"^1.3.3" from
> @tailwindcss/ui@0.3.1 npm ERR! node_modules/@tailwindcss/ui npm ERR!
> dev @tailwindcss/ui@"^0.3" from the root project npm ERR! npm ERR! Fix
> the upstream dependency conflict, or retry npm ERR! this command with
> --force, or --legacy-peer-deps npm ERR! to accept an incorrect (and potentially broken) dependency resolution. npm ERR! npm ERR! See
> /home/tam/.npm/eresolve-report.txt for a full report.
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in: npm ERR!
> /home/xxx/.npm/_logs/2021-07-26T19_33_44_249Z-debug.log

Stuck here. It's a pity as I prefer Tailwind to Bootstrap.

Comment: add package.json pls.

Answer (score 4):

@tailwindcss/ui is [no longer needed](https://tailwindui.com/changes-for-v2#tailwindcss-ui-is-no-longer-needed). Uninstall the @tailwindcss/ui package.

```
npm uninstall @tailwindcss/ui
```

Install latest dependencies for Laravel Mix, Autoprefixer, and PostCSS.

```
npm install -D laravel-mix@latest postcss@latest 
    autoprefixer@latest tailwindcss@latest
```

Finally, make sure the line...

```
require('@tailwindcss/ui'),
```

Is removed from your tailwind.config.js file.

Continue on with your compilation.

```
npm install && npm run dev
```